# Steam "Connect" Protocol

Tags: steam, pc

I currently have a link set on my website to run the following

```
steam://connect/188.141.19.52:27016
```

When it runs, it launches Insurgency Standalone but it doesn't connect. If a person uses `connect 188.141.19.52:27016` in the Insurgency console it works fine;

This works locally if I put it as

```
steam://connect/192.168.0.26:27016
```

Which is the local IP that this server is being hosted on.
Ports are forwarded in Windows Firewall & on Gateway, server displays fine on the in-game server browser and sites such as gametracker display the server fine too.

If I click the link on the website to initiate the connection file then it launches the game and joins no server, it just sits at the menu; but if I Alt+Tab out and click the link again, it connects to the server once it's maximized again.

It's just the original `steam://connect/188.141.19.52:27016` that won't work what-so-ever.

The server itself is connected to my own AD Domain with DNS set up.

Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the server from the same LAN?  Most consumer routers won't like this, since you're using an external IP to access an internal resource.

Comment: I have a player who is trying to connect externally and nothing seems to happen for him.

I have also tried myself and it works if I alt-tab out of the game, click the hotlink and alt-tab back in; the only difference with me using a LAN IP is that it connects as soon as the game launches.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forward just this one port or all ports listed here:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711

The connect string you supply will, indeed, cause the server `188.141.19.52` to be polled by UDP on port `27016` by Steam. This makes sense why the client can then determine what game to launch (how it knows that you want Insurgency rather than HL2:DM or some other Source game).

It could be that the client may attempt to communicate on another port and fail; but the server browser will still work.

The connection working after the program is already launched is an odd behavior, but it may be that a different bootstrap mechanisms are used when the game is already running - one that's more aggressive. Or possibly, it's a side-effect of attempting to connect twice (perhaps the NAT is in a different state for the 2nd attempt - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).